# Jquery - Firefox having slow .live() hover speeds, Chrome & IE are fast

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

OK, so I am working on a new website. Its a social networking type website and it has a lot of jquery interactivity.

Problem comes in when I try using the JQuery.live() for mouseover effects. It runs Very fast in Chrome & Safari, Pretty fast in IE, and slow in Firefox. Very strange as almost always FF is way faster than IE(8/9).

Page in question:
http://www.modelfy.com/user/22/info

If you hover over the 'latest pictures' in chrome and then in Firefox you will notice a huge difference in speed.

```
$('.hoverme').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    $(this).addClass('hoverclass');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('hoverclass');
  }
});
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Also, is .live the best option for optimization?

Thanks!

Comment: IE is _fast_? Weird! I know that FF's javascript engine is slower than Chrome's, I use a lot of jQuery and have also noticed the difference, but back to my first point.. Ie is... _fast_?

Comment: You use .live() quite a lot, I get the feeling a mutation event check failed for FF in the jQuery library and it's checking all .live selectors each mouseover/out.

Comment: PS. for a lot of cases, you might to ponder using CSS :hover in your stylesheet and cut away a lot of javascript executions/dependencies.

Comment: Yes I do have quiet a few .live's listening. @bgerrissen can you be a little more specific to the explination. Im more of a PHP person than a Javascript person. Also, I think you are correct about the :hover in CSS. I will try to eliminate some jquery listeners by doing tat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not totally sure why firefox is slower but you can try to add a context element. Instead of binding all events to the root element you can do something like this:

```
$('div.clickme', $('#recent_photos')[0]).live('mouseover mouseout', function() {
  ...
});
```

Doing this minimizes the amount of traversal and the amount of events bound to the same node.

To figure out which function call is slow you can profile your code with firebug. To get useful results you have to use the uncompressed version of jQuery.

Comment: I removed a lot of .live('mouseover mouseout') for css :hover that was only changing the style of the element.

Comment: Also I did do this as I read up a lot on delegate and live and the performance effects. Thats for the Tip!